SalesForce Messages for in-app [iOS swift SDK] how can I set PreChatFields and HiddenPreChatFields? v1.5.2
OpenChat

    let preChatValue = "myValue"
    let preChatKey = "Somename"
    let config = UIConfiguration(serviceAPI: serviceAPIURL,
                                 organizationId: organizationId,
                                 developerName: developerName,
                                 conversationId: conversationId)

    let coreClient = CoreFactory.create(withConfig: config)

    let myPreChatDelegate = HiddenPrechatDelegateImplementation(preChatValue: preChatValue, preChatKey: preChatKey)
    coreClient.preChatDelegate = myPreChatDelegate
    // Need to add some code to add preChatField with name(preChatKey) and value (preChatValue) 


HiddenPrechatDelegateImplementation
import Foundation
import SMIClientCore // Import the Salesforce SDK; you need to confirm the correct module name.

class HiddenPrechatDelegateImplementation: HiddenPreChatDelegate {
  
  var preChatValue: String
  var preChatKey: String
  
  init(preChatValue: String, preChatKey: String) {
    self.preChatValue = preChatValue
    self.preChatKey = preChatKey
  }
  
  func core(_ core: CoreClient,
            conversation: Conversation,
            didRequestPrechatValues hiddenPreChatFields: [HiddenPreChatField],
            completionHandler: HiddenPreChatValueCompletion) {

    // Use the conversation object to inspect info about the conversation

    // Pass pre-chat fields back to SDK
    completionHandler(hiddenPreChatFields)
  }
  
}

docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-in-app/guide/ios-core-sdk.html#handle-a-pre-chat-form
repo: https://github.com/Salesforce-Async-Messaging
I tried to set prechat field from swift code (ios swift)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I had a similar issue.  I had to set the scope of the prechat handler to be global where I was registering the prechat handler with the core configuration.
If you do it like this:
var prechatHandler: HiddenPreChatDelegateImplementation? (class scope)

When you initiate:
let myPrechatDelegate = HiddenPreChatDelegateImplementation
core.setPreChatDelegate(delegate: myPreChatDelegate, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
self.prechatHandler = myPrechatDelegate

